# recoll (desktop-search engine): error-message in a popup-window

Tags: lubuntu, recoll

when starting **recoll** (e.g. after booting up the computer) the GUI opens alright. After typing  a search-term the search begins but I get an error-message in a popup:

> Aufrund von Einschränkungen der Indizierungs-Bibliothek führt ein
>   Abbruch zur Beendigung des Programms

, which translates roughly into

> Due to limitations of the indexing library, aborting causes the
>   program to terminate.

The search itself seems to work though and produces the desired results.

When closing  recoll and then opening again this phenomenon cannot be observed any more. It works without complaints. 
Curious thing though:
When using recoll  a while afterwards (e.g. 2 hours later) the error-message  pops up again.

BTW: terminal says: "'recoll' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Adressbereichsfehler)"

Why is that and what could I do?

P.S.:
my system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

O.K.,
seems I could sort it out with the help of *medoc*.
I posted a ticket here: https://opensourceprojects.eu/p/recoll1/tickets/68/
and got help from recoll support.
This actually isn´t an error:

> This is not really an error. The important part is the first phrase
>   "Query in progress"
>
> This message appears when a query does not return instantaneously
>   (takes more than a few seconds).
>
> This is to warn the user that it is possible to abort the search, but
>   that the GUI will have to exit (because the Xapian developpers refuse
>   to implement cancellation points).
>
> You don't get it the second time because the data is in the cache, so
>   the search goes faster.